# “Unfortunately, Google Play services has stopped.” on Android L Developer Preview

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-play-services, 5.0-lollipop

I'm running the Android L Developer Preview on my Nexus 5. I'm trying to install the Google Inbox beta, but I can only get to the sign up screen. I always get a ""Unfortunately, Google Play services has stopped" message once I press the sign up button. I'm wondering if there's a way to fix this issue besides reverting to KitKat 4.4. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem -- Google Inbox, developer preview on Nexus 5, same error. I looked at the log (CatLog) and it's showing a runtime exception "UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2" on AccountPickerActivity.

A friend said it works on his Nexus 5 after he flashed the latest developer preview image, so you may want to either do that or just wait a couple weeks for the official 5.0 update. I've had several problems like this on the preview version that I have.

Answer (score 1):

You might try capturing a [log](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_debugging_with_logcat) of the app crashing, and google the resulting error.  You may also want to provide it here for people to look at.  (Be sure there's no private info in there such as login info).  You can paste it to gist.github.com or pastebin.com and then just share the link.  Also try IRC or one of the android forums and people might be able to help you out.